# Add <span> to part of a label using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a span to only part of a label using jQuery. I'm able to isolate the section I want to add the span to (view my fiddle and inspect via the console), but now that I've got that, I don't know how to add the actual span. I need this in order to style a specific section of the label (in this case "red" as an example). Unfortunately, the markup is dynamically generated, so I can't just manually add it.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Currell/mmendnd4/2/).

Here are my watered-down code snippets if you'd prefer to view them here:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" /><label> Some Number (XXXXXX1234)</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" /><label> Some Other Number (XXXXXX4567)</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" /><label> Some Number (XXXXXX7890)</label>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    color: red;
}
```

JS:

```
var label = $('label');

$.each(label, function() {

    var arr = $(this).text().split(' '),
        num = arr[arr.length-1];

    console.log(num);

});
```

This is what I'm starting with:

```
<input type="checkbox" /><label> Some Number (XXXXXX1234)</label><br />
```

And this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<input type="checkbox" /><label> Some Number <span>(XXXXXX1234)</span></label><br />
```

There will by multiple inputs throughout the site, hence $.each.

I've found partial answers to this dilemma on Stack Overflow, just not the right combination to complete the task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Match it with a regex and insert the spans in strings returned to the `html()` function

```
$('label').html(function(_,html) {
    return html.replace(/(\(.*?\))/, "<span>$1</span>");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/mmendnd4/3/)

If you want to split on spaces and get the last part, you can do that instead

```
$('label').html(function(_,html) {
    var parts = html.split(" ");
    var last  = parts.pop();
    parts.push('<span>', last, '</span>');
    return parts.join(" ");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/mmendnd4/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Finishing up the approach you started with: set the element text to everything *before* the last section, then append the span and its contents:

```js
var label = $('label');

$.each(label, function() {

  var el = $(this),
     arr = el.text().split(' '),
     num = arr[arr.length - 1],
    rest = arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1).join(' ');

  el.
    text(rest + " ").
    append($('<span>').text(num));
});
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" />
<label>Some Number (XXXXXX1234)</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" />
<label>Some Other Number (XXXXXX4567)</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" />
<label>Some Number (XXXXXX7890)</label>
```

Comment: What would that change?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below working code snippet.I hope it will solve the issue

```
var label = $('label');

$.each(label, function() {

    var arr = $(this).text().split(' '),
        num = arr[arr.length-1], modifiedText = '<span>'+num+'</span>', finalText= $(this).text().replace(num, modifiedText);

    $(this).html(finalText)

});
```